# Ruby - ERROR: While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)

Tags: ruby

Whenever I tried to install gems recently I am getting the below error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
    the scheme http does not accept registry part: www-cache.reith.bbc.co.uk;htt
p: (or bad hostname?)
```

I am getting this error only recently. Earlier I could install all the gems without any issues. Now, only uninstalling of gems is possible.

I have gone through many solutions and I could find them not specific to my problem.

Comment: This looks like you either have some proxy defined or an additional gem source with a malformed URL. These can be defined either in an environment variable, your `.gemrc` or bundler config in the `.bundle` directory. Without more information however, it is really hard to help you.

Comment: Hi Holger, please let me know the information you need. Also I dont have idea of where the .gemrc and the .bundle directory is.

Comment: well, the full command you are executing, the full error message (+ stack trace if any), your configuration, i.e. the files mentioned in my previous comments, your environment (i.e. the output of the `env` command).

Comment: The .gemrc is typically in `~/.gemrc`. You can also check the output of `gem env`.

Comment: The command I execute in the command prompt is gem install mini_magick -v '3.5.0'. I am unable to post the output of my gem env as its too long.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the data there.

Comment: run this command "pod repo list".If its more than one repo  then i think remove cocoapods and install it again

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, when I copied the command sudo gem install fastlane –NV from the web, -NV contains a bad character, replace dash with a new one and it works fine